# Rails validates_uniqueness_of ignoring scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, validates-uniqueness-of

I’m very new to Rails and am having trouble with Rails/ActiveRecord seemingly ignoring scope on a `validates_uniqueness_of` declaration in a project I’ve inherited. I have the following model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  …
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, scope: :brand_id, allow_nil: true
  …
  belongs_to :brand
  …
end
```

There is an existing user record with an `email` of `foo@bar.com` and a `brand_id` of `1`.

When trying to update another user record with an `id` of `123`, `email` of `foo@bar.com` and a `brand_id` of `2`, I get a `Validation failed: Email has already been taken` error.

I see the following two queries run one after the other when this error occurs:

```
SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'foo@bar.com' AND "users"."id" != 123) LIMIT 1;
SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'foo@bar.com' AND "users"."id" != 123 AND "users"."brand_id" = 2) LIMIT 1;
```

It looks like the second query is doing the correct uniqueness check, but the first one is ignoring the scope.

Any tips on what to look at or how to debug further would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your logic in the model. There's something else that's stopping the Record to save.

Can you put the whole model?

```
class Artwork < ApplicationRecord

  ...

  validates_uniqueness_of :artwork_file_name, scope: :game_id

  ...

end


2.3.1 :810 > Artwork.new(artwork_file_name: 'asd', game_id: 100).save
   (12.5ms)  BEGIN
  Artwork Exists (92.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `artworks` WHERE `artworks`.`artwork_file_name` = BINARY 'asd' AND `artworks`.`game_id` = 100 LIMIT 1
  SQL (64.1ms)  INSERT INTO `artworks` (`game_id`, `artwork_file_name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (100, 'asd', '2017-02-17 10:25:25', '2017-02-17 10:25:25')
   (17.9ms)  COMMIT
 => true
2.3.1 :811 > Artwork.new(artwork_file_name: 'asd', game_id: 100).save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Artwork Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `artworks` WHERE `artworks`.`artwork_file_name` = BINARY 'asd' AND `artworks`.`game_id` = 100 LIMIT 1
   (6.1ms)  ROLLBACK
 => false
2.3.1 :812 > Artwork.new(artwork_file_name: 'asd', game_id: 101).save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Artwork Exists (45.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `artworks` WHERE `artworks`.`artwork_file_name` = BINARY 'asd' AND `artworks`.`game_id` = 101 LIMIT 1
  SQL (6.7ms)  INSERT INTO `artworks` (`game_id`, `artwork_file_name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (101, 'asd', '2017-02-17 10:26:05', '2017-02-17 10:26:05')
   (6.3ms)  COMMIT
 => true
2.3.1 :813 >
```

Comment: I've tracked it down to Devise validating that the email is unique.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be Devise's "validatable" behaviour, which added it's own unique validation of the email field.